# Copy Activity fails from ADO (Odata) Source to Azure Data lake

Tags: azure-data-factory, ado, azure-data-lake

I need to copy data from ADO(OData) to Azure Data lake. All connections and Linked services are working good.

I can preview data from ADO(OData) but getting below error and seems like data is not passed to Datalake and can't able preview data into Datalake side.

```
ErrorCode=ODataFailedClientCreation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to create odata connection to RequestUrl.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.ODataConnector,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to get metadata of odata service, please check if service url and credential is correct and your application has permission to the resource. Expected status code: 200, actual status code: 429, response is : {"error":{"code":"0","message":"Request was blocked due to exceeding usage of resource 'ATCPU' in namespace 'VSID'. For more information on why your request was blocked, see the topic \"Rate limits\" on the Microsoft Web site (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=823950).","innererror":{"message":"Request was blocked due to exceeding usage of resource 'ATCPU' in namespace 'VSID'. For more information on why your request was blocked, see the topic \"Rate limits\" on the Microsoft Web site (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=823950).","type":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssServiceException","stacktrace":""}}}. ,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.ODataConnector,'
```

Comment: Welcome to https://stackoverflow.com/. Please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask . 

You should provide a reproduceable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> actual status code: 429
>
> Error message - "message":"Request was blocked due to exceeding usage
> of resource 'ATCPU' in namespace 'VSID'.

Reason for above error -

Azure DevOps currently has a global consumption limit. This limit delays requests from individual users beyond a threshold when shared resources are in danger of being overwhelmed.

**Global consumption limit**

This limit is focused exclusively on avoiding outages when shared resources are close to being overwhelmed. Individual users typically only have their requests delayed when one of the following occurs:

•   One of their shared resources is at risk of being overwhelmed

•   Their personal usage exceeds 200 times the consumption of a typical user within a (sliding) five-minute window

The amount of the delay depends on the user's sustained level of consumption. Delays range from a few milliseconds per request up to 30 seconds. Once consumption goes to zero or the resource is no longer overwhelmed, the delays stop within five minutes. If consumption remains high, delays may continue indefinitely to protect the resource.

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/rate-limits?view=azure-devops